# NPE in Feign client while decoding ResponseEntity<Void>

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I've got a simple Rest Controller that returns ResponseEntity<Void>. I'm trying to call it though Feign client and getting NPE while decoding the result. Spring cloud version: Angel.SR3, Feign version: 8.9.0

Changing the return value to ResponseEntity<String> and passing some dummy value solves the problem, but is it supposed to work with Void return type?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:43)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:146)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:118)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:71)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.testPost(Unknown Source)
at com.test.TestResource.testGet(TestResource.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class TestResource {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    ResponseEntity<Void> testPost() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Feign Client to access the rest resource:

```
@FeignClient("order-service")
public interface TestClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    ResponseEntity<Void> testGet();
}
```

Call of the feign client:

```
@Service
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private TestClient testClient;

    void test() {
        testClient.testGet(); // this line triggers NPE
    }
}
```

Comment: please log an issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues

Comment: [issue created](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/539)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on the 1.0.x line and will be in Angel.SR4, it already worked in Brixton.M1, but I forward ported the test. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/539 for the commits.